# How to make application auto updates secure

Tags: security, github, auto-update

I am developing an application and I thought it would be nice if it would have an auto update feature.

It's a nodejs application and I'm using electron-builder.

My problem is how secure is that. since if someone gets a hold of your github api token he can potentially publish malicious code in all of your client's computers. Which is even worse when the client is a big company. It could harm them internally.

I know all the most popular applications have auto updates, how do they manage that securely?

Answer (score 0):

> since if someone gets a hold of your github api token he can potentially publish malicious code in all of your client's computers.

Beside having a token with a [limited scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/), [electron-userland/electron-builder issue 1393](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1393) mentions you are supposed to have an org and created a DEDICATED user.

> Only in this case you can share access token somehow

That is a [machine user](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users), but it does require an organization.

It means the token will be able only to read and access release from a particular organization, as a machine user.